# Printing Nested Schema in Marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have these classes as my models with SQLAlchemy. I have successfully gotten marshmallow to encode my user object, however it will not encode the nested link object. My SQLAlchemy query is doing a join of the links table on the fk, which is working correctly. I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my NestedSchema and why it won't encode!

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column('username', String(255), unique=True)
    link = relationship("Link", backref='user', lazy='joined')


class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(255))
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=True)

class LinkSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    user = fields.Nested('UserSchema')


class UserSchema(Schema):
    username = fields.Str()
    links = fields.Nested('LinkSchema')
```

I have a function that queries my database that looks like this. This returns the user and links properly.

```
def get_user(user_id):
    session = get_session()
    try:
       user = session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id)
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError:
       return False
   return user
```

In my flask route this is what I am executing. I am able to properly get my userinfo back, however Marshmallow is not encoding the link part. I know it's there because of the printing link.name[0]. I have looked through the documentation many times and simply cannot figure out what is going wrong. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
@app.route('/api/user_info/)
def get_user_info():
    user = get_user(user_id)
    for u in user:
        print (u.link[0].name) #this prints the link name so I know its there
    schema = UserSchema(strict=True, many=True)
    result = schema.dumps(user)
    pprint(result.data, indent=2)
    return result.data
```

This is the json that is returned. No links! Can't figure out why. I have left out a lot of the columns for brevity sake.

```
[{"username": "erick", "role": 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

after many hours of frustrating, I needed 'links' to be 'link' and many=True in the nested UserSchema.